# Relationship between short-time and large-frequency asymptotics in Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, asymptotics, signal-processing

I am trying to understand how the short-time behaviour of a function $f(t)$ influences the large-frequency asymptotics of its Fourier transform $g(\omega)=\mathcal{F}[f(t)](\omega)\equiv \tilde{f}(\omega)$, in case it exists. I have read sometimes, and it's apparently very intuitive (not to me), that those limits are directly related, but I don't know how to put this on formal grounds or whether is just loosely stated. As far as I understand, one can define an [uncertainty principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Uncertainty_principle) relating the characteristic "width" of each function, but this does not tell us anything about the behaviour at large frequencies themselves (in an "absolute" sense). Maybe I am misunderstanding something very basic here.

I came across this doubt while reading [this paper](http://www3.ul.ie/gleesonj/Papers/Gleeson_SIAP06.pdf), where asymptotic expressions for the short-time limit of the autocorrelation function and the large-frequency behaviour of the power spectrum are derived. At the end of page 13 of the linked pdf file, it is stated:

> A small-$\tau$ expansion of $R(\tau)$ from (43) yields $R(\tau)\sim a - 2(1-i\delta)|\tau|+\mathcal{O}(\tau^2,a^{-1})$ as $\tau\rightarrow 0, a\rightarrow \infty$ and the *corresponding* large-frequency asymptotic form of the spectrum $F(\omega)$ from (20) is $F(\omega)\sim\frac{4}{\omega^2}+\mathcal{O}(\omega^{-3})$ as $\omega\rightarrow \infty$,

where $R(\tau)$ is the autocorrelation function, $a$ and $\delta$ are constants and $F(\omega)=2\Re{\int_0^{\infty}d\tau e^{i\omega\tau}R(\tau)}$ is the power spectrum. The original $R(\tau)$ from which the approximation is derived is

\begin{equation}
R(\tau)=a(a_0+a_1 e^{-2a\tau}+a_2 e^{-4a\tau})e^{-D(\tau)},
\end{equation}
where $D(\tau)=\frac{1}{a}\tau+\frac{\delta^2}{2a^2}(2a\tau+e^{-2a\tau}-1)$, $a_0=\left( 1+\frac{\delta}{2a^2}i\right)^2$, $a_1=\frac{1}{2a^2}\left( 1+\frac{\delta^2}{a^2}-2\delta i \right)$ and $a_2=-\frac{\delta^2}{2a^4}$.

I understand how to get the approximation for $R(\tau)$, but I don't see how to obtain from there the asymptotics for $F(\omega\rightarrow\infty)$ and how they are related, even though it seems to be trivial for the authors.

To sum up: I'd be interested to know how short-time and large-frequency limit are related (or whether this is only valid e.g. when $f(t)$ is peaked around $t=0$ and there is a characteristic width $\delta t$) and in particular how to obtain the large-frequency asymptotics for the case outlined above.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The large frequency asymptotic is related to the points of nonanalyticality of $R(\tau)$. For autocorrelation functions this is typically at $\tau=0$ as the functions are even under $\tau \mapsto -\tau$ but still have a finite derivative...

It is a well-known theorem of Fourier analysis: if a function $R(\tau)$ has $n$ continuous derivatives, its Fourier transform decays like $$F(\omega) \propto \frac1{\omega^{2+n}}.$$

For example $R(\tau) = \exp(-\gamma |\tau|)$ is continuous but has no continuous derivative ($n=0$), and thus we have $F(\omega) \propto \omega^{-2}$.